# amsmath alignment referring to equal sign or ampersand?

Tags: equations, amsmath, ampersand

I am wondering why the `aligned` environment aligns the equations on the right to the equal sign, and not to the ampersand given in the code before `Nu` and `Sh`. This code actually produces the output I want. But I need to understand why it does that for a more complex case. Here's the code and the output:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[c]
Nu*&=2+\frac{Nu_0-2}{F_T};\hspace{3cm}&Nu_0=2+0.552Re^{1/2}Pr^{1/3}\\
Sh*&=2+\frac{Sh_0-2}{F_M};&Sh_0=2+0.552Re^{1/2}Sc^{1/3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Because the second `&` is only to create another column of alignments, which uses the 3rd `&` to align to. If you really want to align `N` and `S` from the right column, use `&&N... ` and `&&S...`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! More generally, `n` alignment columns require `2n –1` ampersands, since all columns but the first need to be introduced by an ampersand. Also, to control the spacing between columns, use preferably `alignat` (or ` alignedat` ).

Comment: your question is not very clear, the alignment is at the _left_ of the equals, where the ampersand is, as you can see if you use relations of different lengths, obviously the two = are the same, so if the left edge aligns the right edge aligns also.

Answer (score 3):

The `&` are incorrectly placed in the example, there is no alignment of the second =, the terms are set flush right so the = only look aligned as the terms have similar length. If you lengthen one you see

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[c]
Nu*&=2+\frac{Nu_0-2}{F_T};\hspace{3cm}&Nu_0=2+0.552Re^{1/2}Prr^{1/3}\\
Sh*&=2+\frac{Sh_0-2}{F_M};&Sh_0=2+0.552Re^{1/2}Sc^{1/3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `&` should always be placed to the left of the equality and between the equations so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[c]
Nu*&=2+\frac{Nu_0-2}{F_T};\hspace{2cm}&Nu_0&=2+0.552Re^{1/2}Prr^{1/3}\\
Sh*&=2+\frac{Sh_0-2}{F_M};&Sh_0&=2+0.552Re^{1/2}Sc^{1/3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

AMS alignments work like `array` with a column specification of `{rlrlrlrlrl}` so the term to the left of each relation is aligned to the right, towards the relation and the term to right (which includes the relation) is aligned to the left.